# Redirect all traffic from different domains to same page temporarily

Tags: redirect, http-redirect

We have several websites in a **shared hosting** account. We also manage in that account many domains/subdomains that point to those websites. I would like to know if there's any way to redirect all incoming traffic of that server (well, our part of the server since it's shared) from any domain to a specific page in the same server.

The reason to do this is because we're changing stuff around with the databases, files, etc that affect multiple websites at the same time, so instead of going one by one setting an "site under maintenance, please come back later" notice individually, I'd be better to just do it once for all of them, and once we're done, leave everything as it was before.

Any ideas if this is possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to look at htaccess redirection rules, 
something like :

for example .htaccess content :

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: well, correct me if I'm wrong, but that would be fine if all domains/subdomains currently pointed to a same folder in the server... but then I wouldn't have any issue. My "problem" is that all domains point to different folders, and I'm looking for a solution that allows me to set something up in just one place instead of in every folder